# AngularJS UI-Router does not work as the way ng-router works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm trying to use angular ui-router library which has more features than the ng-router.
However, ng-router works in the page while ui-router does not work.

Angular Code

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('map.main', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
    });

    //$routeProvider.when(
    //"/", {
    //    template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
    //});
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

HTML code is very simple
with a div tag for ng-view or ui-view.

Anyone can think about any problems?

Comment: does your state has `map` as parent state, & add your html..

Comment: nice. you solved my problem. I dont have a parent state! I did not notice the dot is for nested views.

Comment: I've added answer,please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EVYdsWqiK5BbZW90pF3I?p=preview)

You would need to adjust your state def at least like this

```
.state('map', {
  abstract: true,
  template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
})
.state('map.main', {
  url: '/',
  template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
});
```

What we can see, there is new state "map" which is a parent of "map.main". This is a **must** if we want to have state "map.main". The dots (.) are information for UI-Router, that the state is built as hierarchy (parent map, child main)

Also, in our index.html we have to create a target:

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

this will serve as a placeholder, for our parent. Child will then be injected into parent's `template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',`

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EVYdsWqiK5BbZW90pF3I?p=preview)

Try to read more here:

- [UI-Router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)
- example application and its great state defintion [contact.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js)

Comment: Thanks! What if I enable HTML5 mode..My url is like http:localhost:1234/map.

Comment: That is also about the Server. You have to be sure, that server will be able to handle that. Check my adjusted example with that in play - http://plnkr.co/edit/6jgU7wXKgZrvvv26EKsE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring child route without defining parent route,
You should declare parent state first and then add your code

**Code**

```
$stateProvider
.state('map', {
    abstract: true, //you can't call it directly
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>'
}).state('map.main', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<h1>My Contacts</h1>'
});
```